# Get height and width of iframe

Tags: jquery

I would like to get height and width data of an vimeo iframe (in jquery). I would like to use this datas to put them for the div `popin`.

```
<div class="popin">
    <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video....." frameborder="0" width="640" height="320"></iframe>
</div>

.popin {
    max-width: ?? iframe value;
    max-height: ?? iframe value;
}
```

Comment: if you look closely at the iframe syntax you can see a width and height property with some values in it

Comment: @madalinivascu ok but I need to get this iframe value

Comment: what iframe value?

Comment: @madalinivascu The width and height values of my iframe. I need to get them. To put them in my popin div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `attr()` to select the with and the height

```
var width = $('iframe[src*=vimeo]').attr('width');
var height = $('iframe[src*=vimeo]').attr('height');
$('.popin').css({maxWidth:width+'px',maxHeight:height+'px'});
```

Comment: Thank you. But i Have the error : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token - for the last line